# JQuery toggle class plus animation

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

i have this code but don't know why the 'toggleClass' instruction doesn't work. can someone give me any tips? http://jsfiddle.net/dW6Mb/16/. Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#admin > p').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('adminPvisible');
    var right = $('#admin > p').css('right') == '135px' ? '0' : '135px';
    $('#admin > p').animate({
        right: right,
        width: '50px'
    });
    $('#admin > form, #btn').stop(true).slideToggle();        
})
```

})

Comment: You can just specify `width: 50` instead of `width: '50px'`: jQuery deals with this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```
#admin .adminPvisible {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8KNJc/)

You have a rule `#admin p` which is setting the opacity to `.3` and then you are assigning the class `adminPvisible`(with opacity `1`) to the `p` element, but since the id rule has more weight it is overriding the class rule

Comment: Thanks, i could overcome this problem with the '!important' in css class. Thank you, i understood what you mean now.

Comment: @Miguel see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css